# What should I learn? What´s next?

Tags: guitar, theory, piano

So in 3 days I´ve learned and memorized most of the basics/foundations and like certain rules in music theory: How to spell, build Major/Minor Chords/Scales, What Diatonics Chords they contain, Cycle of Fifth/fourth, Relative M/m Keys, Chord Scales, Roman Numerals + some Progression but I thought am I learning things that I need? I have the knowledge but I CAN´T make music out of it.. yet

My Goals are: Improvising from the head, Figuring out songs by ear and play them in my style, playing Jazz, Funk, (Groove)
I´ve hit a wall and so what am I supposed to learn (theory wise) for my goals?

Comment: If you've managed all that in 3 days, you'll have no trouble filling the rest of the gaps that take most of us years to achieve.

Comment: 3 whole days with 4 hours of sleep everyone could've achieve that if they put some effort in it... but I want to learn the essentials and not "unnecessary" stuff which I don't need for my playing.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to teach yourself how to make music by learning the rules, i.e. using a formulaic approach.  You may have unique abilities that most of us do not but it is close to impossible to learn that way.  Everything you list is "essential" but it takes time to see the connections between the topics so you can appreciate them.  Playing and listening are better than formulas.

Comment: @ggcg well said! I need a source where I can look back at and relate how/why they are playing like that but by now I have so much information in my head that I don't know what to do with this knowledge except sitting around in the corner... I guess I just need to start playing more and by ear. Thanks mate!

Comment: Music theory is great but playing is music.  There are great players out there that cant even read music.  I am not an advocate of illiteracy but we usually learn to speak by imitation then learn grammar.  Music playing and music theory work better in that order (in my experience).

Answer (score 5):

Play music.

It sounds simple, but it's vital. You don't learn to speak English by memorising a dictionary and grammar textbook. Not to say that  knowledge is useless; far from it. But there's no substitute for listening, and then joining in yourself.

So, find a band, and play really badly for a while. If you want to, you'll get better. Listen to lots of music, and not as sonic wallpaper. Train your ears to break down what you are hearing, and then imitate it. You'll soon start to recognise how that theory maps to what you hear. That's when it becomes really powerful.

Comment: I came to say the same. You beat me to it. By breaking down the music you hear you will either apply what you already know or uncover stuff you don't know yet.

Comment: It's just in my nature to understand the mechanics and such before doing something wether it is in gaming, sports... I'm too much of a theorist and I forget the joy of playing and I really appreciate your answers, it makes sense!

Comment: @VoAnton As an engineer, I do relate to that mindset :). Often people underplay the value of the theory, so knowing it is very useful. But not at the expense of, well, underplaying.